# Can the network indicator be hidden?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, network-manager

Using 11.04. The network indicator is visible at all times, but this isn't necessary for me, it just adds clutter. Is there any way to hide/remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is no, the indicators cannot be individually enabled or disabled, however you can kill the network indicator by running the following command: `pkill nm-applet`

To restart the network indicator, run `nm-applet`

To turn off the network indicator so it doesn't show up at all when you log in:

1. Click the power icon in the top right corner and select *System
   Settings*.
2. Click *Startup Applications* in the Personal section.
3. Uncheck the Network Manager item.

Be aware that killing the network indicator will **not** allow you to connect to wireless networks.

Comment: Thanks. I was particularly wondering about how it would affect my ability to connect which was clearly answered.