# How to find and start/stop or hide/display indicators?

Tags: unity, indicator, process, applet

I am using Ubutnu 14.04 (LTS) and have following indicators:
[image]

Now from above indicators (like: Bluetooth, Classic-Menu, Indicator-synapse, Network, Laungage, Message, Sound , datetime or calendar and last power/setting management).

I want to start/stop or hide/display some of them.

Ex (I only know for one): I know that NetworkManager can be displayed with `nm-applet` and can be started/stopped by `sudo service network-manager`. (classic-menu and synapse are user indicator)

Thus I want to know how other indicators (ex: for language, message, datetime and specially last indicator) can be displayed and hide or started and stopped?

What command or applet can I use?

Comment: take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/73200/how-do-i-add-remove-an-entry-in-the-indicator-applet-in-gnome) and also [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152380/how-can-i-remove-the-default-indicators-and-add-custom-ones)

Comment: @KasiyA 2nd link is a start. Pandya:Bluetooth is a service too (there is a bluetooth in /etc/init.d).  So that works the same as NM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to hide/show some of them:

- Sound

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible false
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
  ```

  or

  ```
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/sound/visible false
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/sound/visible true
  ```
- Keyboard Layout

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible true
  ```

  or

  ```
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/visible false
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/visible true
  ```
- Time

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-clock false
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-clock true
  ```

  or

  ```
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/show-clock false
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/show-clock true
  ```
- Bluetooth

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth visible false
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth visible true
  ```

  or

  ```
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/bluetooth/visible false
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/bluetooth/visible true
  ```
- Power

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.power icon-policy 'never'
  gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.power icon-policy 'present'
  ```

  or

  ```
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/power/icon-policy 'never'
  dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/power/icon-policy 'present'
  ```

Comment: I think it is better to use `gsettings`. So, I suggest you to add configuration by using `gsettings`, or replace `dconf` with `gsettings` if you don't mind.

Comment: No problem @Pandya, answer was updated

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the individual indicator packages entirely using `Synaptic Package Manager`, or blacklist the indicator icons using `Gconf-editor`.

**Messages:** Remove package `indicator-messages`
**Sound:** Remove package `indicator-sound`
**Power: Remove package `indicator-power`

**Date/Time:** Simply enable/disable from System Settings...Time & Date and in the Clock tab unchecked `Show a clock in the menu` option

**volume:** Remove package `indicator-sound`

**Power/Battery:** Remove package `indicator-power`. The battery indicator also is configurable in the power management settings.

**Language:** Simple enable/disable from System Settings...Text Entry and unchecked `Show current input source in the menu bar` option

**Netwok:** Look this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35369/can-the-network-indicator-be-hidden/35421#35421)

**Bluetooth:** Do this steps

1. `cd ~/.config/autostart`
2. `cp /etc/xdg/autostart/bluetooth-applet* .`
3. `echo "Hidden=true" | tee -a bluetooth-applet*`

And the indicator with your **username** and **session management** is called `indicator-session`

#### Note: Removing these default indicators is NOT recommended.

Search for 'indicator' in Synaptic to see more of them.